# How to use openweathermap api key?

Tags: php, api-key, openweathermap, weather-api

I have openweathermap api key , but how can I use it in PHP ? 
and the weather report should be report from a city name, not from the location weather ID

Comment: i got 
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.3048,"country":"GB","sunrise":1409288950,"sunset":1409338405},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10n"}],"base":"cmc stations","main":{"temp":290.39,"pressure":1013,"humidity":77,"temp_min":289.15,"temp_max":291.65},"wind":{"speed":7.2,"deg":240},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1409343901,"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}

so how can i take "  [temp] => 300.15"  value in a variable, to show that one ?

Comment: `'Too broad' my ass` is not a compelling reopen argument. This question contains no coding attempt and no [mcve]. It is a requirements dump.  There is no link to the documentation. No proof of effort at all. Then the comment from the asker is asking how to access json -- which is a dupe question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***How to use API key***

Add the following parameter to the GET request: APPID=APIKEY 
Example: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?APPID=***YOURAPIKEY*** & what ever you want to request.

```
<?php

    $request = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?APPID=***YOURAPIKEY***';
    $response  = file_get_contents($request);
    $jsonobj  = json_decode($response);
    print_r($jsonobj);
?>
```

To request specific information just look at the keys that the API accepts and append & to the end of the url KEY=VAL.

An example would be

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=YourAPIKey&q=London

I would also like to add when working with API's I recommend installing a JSON viewer plugin. I got the JSONView installed as a Google chrome extension which is brilliant for viewing json.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/jsonview?hl=en

Comment: Is it possible to add the api key in header ?