# Convert JSON to GeoJson Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet, geojson

My question has been discussed here, but I could not get my issue solved with the answers, perhaps because of my JavaScript small background.

I am in need to convert an online Json to a Geojson.  My function getmyJson is doing that:

```
var lat=-15.78 //latitude variable
var long=-47.93 //longitude variable
 var data_url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+long+"&appid=111111111111111111111111111";


   function getmyJson(data_url) {
 return JSON.parse($.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: data_url,
     dataType: 'json',
     global: false,
     async:false,
     success: function(data) {

         var outGeoJson = {}
     outGeoJson['properties'] = data
     outGeoJson['type']= "Feature"
     outGeoJson['geometry']= {"type": "Point", "coordinates":
    [data.coord.lon, data.coord.lat]}

    var brasilia = L.geoJson(outGeoJson, { 
     onEachFeature: function (feature, layer)   
            {
            layer.bindPopup("N&#250;mero da RN: "+feature.properties.id+"<br>"+
                            "Localiza&#231;&#227;o: "+feature.properties.name+"<br>"+
                            "longitude: "+feature.geometry.coordinates[0]+"<br>"+
                            "latitude: "+feature.geometry.coordinates[1]
                            );//just to show something in the popup. could be part of the geojson as well!


        }

}).addTo(map);

    return outGeoJson;
     }
 }).responseText);

}
var myweather = getmyJson(data_url);
```

As you can see, I need: 1 - to call the getJson function passing the url [getmyJson(data_url); 2 - convert the Json to GeoJson (var outGeoJson); 3 - to assign the GeoJson to myweather variable ]. 
Everything works fine. However if I move the **code 1** bellow right after the line 
var myweather = getmyJson(data_url); I get the following error:

**Invalid GeoJson Object**

**code 1**

```
var brasilia = L.geoJson(myweather, { 
     onEachFeature: function (feature, layer)   
            {
            layer.bindPopup("N&#250;mero da RN: "+feature.properties.id+"<br>"+
                            "Localiza&#231;&#227;o: "+feature.properties.name+"<br>"+
                            "longitude: "+feature.geometry.coordinates[0]+"<br>"+
                            "latitude: "+feature.geometry.coordinates[1]
                            );//just to show something in the popup. could be part of the geojson as well!


        }

}).addTo(map);
```

Could someone help me to figure out why I am getting this Error?

Thank you for your time and attention in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error? Please explain the problem.

Comment: Hi @styfle. I did some editing in my previous message. The Error is **Invalid GeoJson object**.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35870567/266535

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25575466/266535

Comment: Do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(myweather))` and you will see the problem for your last error. The previous code sample is the correct way of using asynchronous operations. If you want to decouple code, you can wrap in functions or use Promises.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)